# why google play protect mark my application as harmful?

Tags: android, google-play-protect

we have an android application and it's currently published in google play. but when we try to publish it as apk file, google play protect mark it as harmful. we update our app in play store to if our apk have any problem, google play reject it. but google play approve and publish our apk.
my question is

[image]

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/cjCQxkzaqDA

Comment: thank you but this link does not help. we appeal to google protect but still no answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the link below and submit your application:

[Play Protect Appeals Submission Form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals)

After a few days, the problem shall be fixed.

Comment: Should I submit play store link? or just downloadable link? In that Form

Comment: just direct downloadable link. @sriram-c-g

Comment: Okay got it. And also the update is once i submitted in closed beta and downloaded from play store as tester this dint happen. Google protect allows it without the popup.

Comment: How did you get downloadable link ? I tried with dropbox and bit.ly nothing worked :(